# How to crawl a site using Python and Mechanize

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize

How can I use Mechanize with Python to crawl a website, recursively following every link on every page?

Every example I've seen in tutorials and Mechanize documentation shows how to follow a browsing "path" if I can call it that (e.g. go to home page, populate a form, press submit, do something with the response), rather than scraping an entire site.

Comment: you want to restrict it to the site's domain or follow every link to its fullest potential?

Comment: just site's domain, but the solution to my problem wouldn't need to worry about rules like that.

Answer (score 2):

here is some psudo code to get you started, let me know if you need more:

```
br = make browser object
visited=set()
max_depth=10
def crawl_all_links(browser,depth):
    if depth <= max_depth:
        for link in browser.links():
            if link not in visited:
                visited.add(link)
                browser.open(link)
                do_something(browser.read())
                crawl_all_links(browser,depth+1)
                browser.back()

crawl_all_links(browser,0)
```